# Blender 2.79 or 2.8b?

Tags: modeling

I just started working with Blender very recently (about two weeks) and it's been great fun so far. The problem is that I've been using Blender 2.79, not 2.8b. Should I switch to 2.8b and learn how to use its interface or continue using 2.79, of which I'm just starting to get the hang of? Is the difference in controls/interface that big?
Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing at the moment, and what plans you have in the future... The basic concepts and workflow have not changed much, and deep down 2.8 is the same program, but with interface changes. If you are doing any kind of serious work on blender, or have deadlines to meet, stick to 7.9 as it is more stable and documented and it is easier to find help. Down the line, 2.8 will be the new standard and is certainly here to stay.

Comment: 2.80 should be released on July 2019. There is a noticeable difference in UI and controls. Not enough to completely lose your marks if you know 2.7, but enough to require some adaptation time. The only thing important to note is that intil 2.80 is released, the "2.8 daily builds" are unstable, UI and tools may change from one day to another, and it's not recommanded to create importent content with it, as unstability might corrupt your files.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try 2.8 tomorrow and see what it's like for starters. I appreciate the help!